# Using a Cursor Adapter to display TextViews and a RatingBar in the ListView

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm attempting to create a class that extends a CursorAdapter in order to  display a RatingBar and text in the ListView,  using its newView and bindView methods.This is an attempt to go further with the Notepad tutorials from the Dev website.My problem is that the program crashes manly because I'm implementing the methods wrong , although there may be other problems of implementation in this class or the filldata method.My question is what is the correct way to write the code so that I can display a rating bar in a listview along with other textviews?Thank you

```
package com.android.demo.notepad3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

public class NoteA extends BaseAdapter{
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private EditText mTitleText;
    private EditText mBodyText;
    private RatingBar mRatingBar;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    Context c1;
    static Cursor c;
    private static boolean autoRequery;


    public NoteA(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    c1=context;
    this.c=c;
     mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(context);
      mDbHelper.open();

    }
    @Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {


      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, null);
      mTitleText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
      mBodyText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
      mRatingBar= (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);

      mTitleText.setText(c.getString(
             c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
     mBodyText.setText(c.getString(
             c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
     mRatingBar.setRating(c.getFloat(
             c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_RATING)));

    return view;
}
     // @Override
//public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

//}

//@Override
//public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
//final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, parent, false);
//bindView(view, context, cursor);
//return view;
//}



}
```

Filldata method from the Notepad3 class wich extends a ListActivity

```
 private void fillData() {
       Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
       startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
       String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};

       // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
       int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2};

         //Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        ListAdapter notes = new NoteA(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own custom ListView using BaseAdapter..

Like this..

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;

private List<Phonebook> listPhonebook;

public PhonebookAdapter(Context context, List<Phonebook> listPhonebook) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listPhonebook = listPhonebook;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listPhonebook.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listPhonebook.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
 outInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_row, null); //This should be your Layout with the rating bar

 //Here you can get your widgets for use like this..

  TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMobile);
 //You can do the same thing for the Rating bar you.

    }
```

Comment: it doesn't look much different from what I have...also shouldn't I use a CursorAdapter instead of a BaseAdapter as a class extension?

Comment: Check the logcat for the error that occurs when the app crashes

Comment: I've updated the code....now the program runs but it returns nothing...not even when I add a note in the program itself...god I'm so tired

Comment: You need to make sure you are opening your databse too.

Comment: I'm assuming that has to be done in the getView....is there something else I need to consider/do?

Comment: Eveything esle looks correct. Try creating a public method in your DbAdapter class to open the database. Use the method in your getView before you try to retrieve the information in the database.

Comment: that is the fetchAllNotes() which is called in the filldata methods=

Comment: So do you open the database inside of your dbAdapter? You should be opening the database whenever you want to access the database in other activities.

Comment: Now the rating bar is displayed along with the text but when I click the note to edit it it doesn't work it just interacts with the rating bar....

Comment: hmm...Try setting the RatingBar.setFocusable(false); in your code and see what happens. And try EditText.setFocusable(true);

Comment: Thats if you dont want the user to interact with the rating bar at all.

Comment: "Thats if you dont want the user to interact with the rating bar at all." ...only in the edit note section but not in the ListView...

Comment: it works I can access the edit note section,but I can still use the rating bar in the ListView....why? this is weird

Comment: Cool beans!Im glad you got it